# Magento new website/store products links 404 error

Tags: magento-1.7

i have setup new website and store for international customers in magento and published all the products to new website and re-index every thing ,now when i click on any products in new store i get 404 error.

```
store for local market :         ayurvedacart.in
store for International market : ayurvedacart.in/outside (products link having 404 error)
```

i am confused whats wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disabling "Use Web Server Rewrites" solved the problem